# How can I host a React frontend with a Nestjs backend?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, nestjs, firebase-hosting

I am building a project with React as frontend and Nestjs as backend, and everything works perfectly when I start both applications, they can communicate perfectly. But they are in different GitHub repos, and I don't know how can I host them both. To the best of my knowledge, for example if I host both of them on Vercel, they will be on separate domains. I am already hosting the frontend on Firebase, and I haven't found any docs regarding what is the best solution in this case.

I hosted the frontend code on Firebase, but I don't know how should I even start out with deploying my Nestjs server to the cloud.

Comment: You can use Firebase Functions to host your nestjs backend, you can find a quick tutorial [here](https://fireship.io/snippets/setup-nestjs-on-cloud-functions/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options and they may be limited based on where you choose to host your application:

1. Deploy both applications on the same server under the same domain.
2. Deploy the applications to different servers on different sub-domains (e.g. [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) and app.myapp.com)
3. Deploy the applications to different domains.

###### Option 1

This option will depend on where you choose to host your application.  You could create a new repo with all your other two projects in it and deploy that repo to your server.  If your host allows it (for instance if you can run multiple docker images on the same machine) then you can deploy both apps to the same server like that.  There are a few options here.

###### Option 2

Create subdomains within the domain you currently own, configure CORS, and deploy your apps to different servers.  You will need to request different certificates for each server.

###### Option 3

Same as Option 2 except you will need to own two domains.